# Google Chrome not showing microphone permission prompt

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, webrtc, getusermedia

I have a web application that uses the microphone for WebRTC through `getUserMedia`. I currently have this application running on multiple subdomains, like `test.example.com`, `staging.example.com`, `production.example.com`, etc.
On most of them, it works properly.

On one of the domains (`test`), I am unable to use the microphone. My code calls `getUserMedia` with a callback, but the callback is never executed, and the browser's permission prompt is never shown.

I have also reproduced this behavior using the Developer Tools console using the new Promise-based API:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

(Yes, I know it does the same thing for `then` and `catch`, but it doesn't matter for this case.)

On the working site (`stage`, for example) here is the result in the console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
MediaStream {id: "RANDOM_CHARS", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …}
```

On the non-working site, it only shows `Promise {<pending>}`, but the neither `then` nor `catch` logs anything because it never resolves either way.

I have found that if I go into the site settings (`chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.example.com`) and change `Microphone` to `Allow`, then I can refresh the page and it works properly. If I change it back to `Ask`, I get the same behavior again - that it doesn't ask.

This behavior is true about *any* site and *any* permission that I have tested - changing an `Allow`ed permission back to `Ask` doesn't ask. However, on this particular `test` site, I had never before today tried to use it, so there's no reason it would have been set to `Allow` and then back to `Ask` to trigger that behavior.

In all these cases, `navigator.permissions.query({name: "microphone"}).then(console.log)` returns `PermissionStatus {state: "prompt", onchange: null}` as expected.

How can I get Chrome to prompt for microphone permission again?

Comment: Did you solve that anyway? I am having the same issue trying to access video on a device.

Comment: @WagnerBertoliniJunior No, I still have no solution.

Comment: on my case it was caused by the App (Chrome) not having those access on the phone. I gave Chrome the right permissions on Phone and then it started to ask for permission. I just don’t know why the App didn’t had that access before.

Comment: Well my case is on desktop, so that's not it.

Comment: could you try to check if your "test" domain is on https and if the certificate has no issues that prevent it for being "trusted"?

Answer (score -2):

You need a valid domain using https protocol in order to get Chrome to prompt for permissions.